# Windows startup - priority to network or wait for one

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have several applications that launch when I start Windows. All of them access the network (e.g. Web browser, Skype, Steam, etc).

My PC takes about 40-60 seconds to start and then I have to wait another two minutes until the network connection is established. I'm looking for a way to deal with some apps that fail to launch/login during that time.

Is there a way to either give Network the highest priority or make all applications wait until the connection is established?

I use Windows 7 and the connection is wired.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a batch file that would launch all of your application. This way you can setup a sleep or pause at the start of the script to wait until the connection is established. If you want to give this a try I will gladly assist you to create the batch file if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that this should be the solution.